# Strpos not matching Hebrew string

Tags: php, hebrew

I'm trying to find whether a Hebrew string exists using `strpos`. I tried `mb_strpos`, and tried `!strpos`, even `similar_text()` but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

The code:

```
$data1 = file_get_contents('hebrewtext.txt');
$data2 = "אבגדהוזחטיכל";

if(strpos($data1, $data2) === FALSE) {
 # Hebrew string does not exists
}

else {
 # Hebrew string exists
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does "nothing happened" mean that the code didn't execute, or that the string was not found?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang the string was not found

Comment: Have you made sure that your PHP file and the text file have the same encoding? (Not that one is UTF-8 and the other one ISO-something.)

Comment: @Siguza , Pretty much the problem is encoding )

Comment: Where is the problem , works for me. It is working as it is expected to

Comment: @Siguza, The php is UTF-8 and so does the text file

Answer (score 1):

First, at least you have to write your PHP code in `UTF-8`. PHP does not fully support except `ASCII` and `UTF-8`.

If you also wrote `hebrewtext.txt` in `UTF-8`, just use `strpos`. Although returned offset is byte-based not character-based, it's not a problem if you just compare it to `FALSE`.

```
<?php
$data1 = file_get_contents('hebrewtext.txt'); // This file is written in UTF-8
$data2 = "אבגדהוזחטיכל"; // This code is written in UTF-8
var_dump(strpos($data1, $data2) !== FALSE)); // Contains? -> It'll work
```

Otherwise, there are two solutions.

1. Set `mb_internal_encoding` and `mb_strpos` instead of `strpos`
2. Convert content of `hebrewtext.txt` into `UTF-8` using `mb_convert_encoding`

Comment: Check encoding of both `hebrewtext.txt` and `your_script.php`. CP1255? You should convert them into UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

In php, string functions only support [ASCII](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html). So, you will need to use another function which is named mb_strpos (for Multi Byte strpos). Also, since you have to deal with non-ASCII characters, i'd recommend to replace any string functions you use in your code with the equivalent in the multi bytes string functions [library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). (which is standard)

Comment: [Pretty sure "♦" is not ASCII](https://3v4l.org/F4aLr) (and yet, `strpos` works).

Comment: @Siguza replaced link with one that does not include the extended ASCII codes

Comment: I mean to say, your claim that PHP string functions only support ASCII, is wrong. They operate on bytes, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Siguza not documented as such. they only say [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Also, if they they did support other encoding, why does all of the mb_* functions exists and are documented as the multi byte safe functions?

Comment: @Siguza further proof that php's string functions are not multi byte compatible http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php also explain why your exemple work. you probably have a feature enabled that he does not have

Comment: [Doesn't look like mb-overloading is enabled on 3v4l though](https://3v4l.org/jJt16).

Answer (score 0):

Use mb_strpos() and set encoding to UTF-8 with mb_internal_encoding().

Comment: Can you show example? 'cause I tried but maybe you're idea is different

Comment: With UTF-8, you don't have to use `mb_strpos` if you just compare it to `FALSE`. UTF-8 is *Prefix Code*.